# My Two Strange Friends

Tags: pattern

I have two strange friends; they don't seem to get along, and they say phrases that make no sense.

The following are some phrases my first friend has said:

> great trees feared axes
>   
> caged war gave a start
>   
> tears were dared

And the following are some phrases my second friend has said:

> join my monopoly ploy
>   
> mull on my onion opinion
>   
> look upon my mill on my hill

Can you identify my two friends?

Comment: ACDEFGRSTWX vs HIJLMNOPUY (dunno about BKQVZ)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your two friends are

> Your left hand and your right hand

Because

> All of the words your first friend said can be typed with just your left hand on a standard US keyboard with standard touch-typing technique. All the words your second friend said can be typed with just your right.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and good answer! (Also, thanks for using spoiler syntax and explaining your reasoning!)

Comment: Though the real riddle is why he's friends with both his hands :-)

Comment: @Deusovi It seems that Joe should have got 390 rep, although I think he capped the limit. I hope he will get the rest tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know. I know plenty of people who use exactly one finger for the entire keyboard...

Comment: True, which is why I said "with standard touch-typing technique".  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Fun answer.

As [Joe said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41755/26699) the answer is:

> Your left hand and your right hand

And since:

> The Right hand just use the vowels [IOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOU) he is telling you that he owes you something. RUN! HE IS NOT YOUR FRIEND.

Comment: How are those three linked with your right hand [censored] you something?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Search wikipedia for the three letter acronym preceding the part you censored. (trying to avoid spoilers as well)

Comment: @Pablo Oh, I thought it was a real word...